# C# string manipulation Regex or substring?

Tags: c#, regex, string, substring

I have a

```
string CCstring = "CC01=50 CC02=300 CC03=500 CC04=40";
```

I want to store the individual values in seperate strings like:

```
for(int i = 0; i<=4; i++)
{
   string suffix = i.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0');
   string CCindividual = CCindividual + i;
   CCindividual = //THIS IS WHERE I WOULD LIKE TO GET MY INDIVIDUAL VALUES i.e 50,300,500,40;
    Console.WriteLn("CC" + i + " =" + CCIndividual);//Testing
}
```

Which string manipulation should I use Regex or Substring. How would the code snippet look like?

Comment: Old chinese proverb: When face with problem, programmer may decide to use Regex. Programmer now have 2 problem.

Comment: @Jamiec: Didn't know that Jamie Zawinski was chinese :-p (http://regex.info/blog/2006-09-15/247)

Comment: @Joachim - funnily enough I kinda knew that wasnt *really* a chinese proverb. It's just funnier framed as one.

Comment: only true if you don't know how and when to use them...

Comment: @Jamiec: I agree and disagree with you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One line:

```
string[] CCindividual = Regex.Split(CCstring, "CC[0-9]+=").Where(x => x != "").
    Select(x => x.Trim()).ToArray<String>();
```

Not sure this is the more efficient way though.

Comment: Thank you. The snippet: `string[] CCindividual = Regex.Split(tempComms, "CC[1-9]+=");` worked perfectly. I also have other generated elements like CCundefined which are created by JS on unused inputs. Regex elimated that too. Other solutions described here were making it too complicated then its actually is. I know Regex has a beautiful way to simplify complex string operation. Just could not make one. Thanks again.

Comment: The edited version works too. Can you explain what is different in the edited version from the original version and why was it made?

Comment: @SameerShah: I added `.Where(x => x != "")` to remove empty values that you can obtain after doing the `Regex.Split`, and `Select(x => x.Trim())` to remove any trailing spaces (without it, you will obtain `50_`, `300_`, `500_` and `40`, `_` representing a space here).

Comment: I got it. I also would like to remove any alphabets For Eg:
`string tempComms = "CC01=500 CC02=50 CC03=400 CC04=undefined CC06=Blah CC07=4Blah";
string[] CCIndividualEdited = Regex.Split(tempComms, "CC[0-9]+=").Where(x => x != "").Where(x => x != "^[a-zA-Z]+$").Select(x => x.Trim()).ToArray<String>();`

How should I do that.

Comment: You mean like this:
`string[] Comm = Regex.Split(tempComms, "CC[1-9]+=").Where(x => x != "").Where(x => x = Regex.Match( "[0-9]+")).Select(x => x.Trim()).ToArray<String>();`

Comment: Depends. You need to precise more what do you want to retrieve. In `CC07=4Blah`, do you want to retrieve the `4` or nothing? In `CC08=1x2y3z`, do you want to retrieve `1` only or `{1,2,3}` or `123`?

Comment: Nothing. The whole thing should be discarded. Eg CC07=4Blah then CC07 value will never be considered. But, I solved it using other function in js(also Regex) where I do not allow such characters rather than making this statement more complicated.

Thanks a lot for you help Sir.

Answer (score 2):

Neither. You can use `string.Split` to get an array:

```
string CCstring = "CC01=50 CC02=300 CC03=500 CC04=40";
string[] strings = CCstring.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

After that, you are able to do the same for the `=` using `string.Split(new char[] { '=' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);`.

Comment: You then have to remove `"CCXX="`.

Answer (score 2):

Can't you use split to first split on spaces and next on '='? It's easier than regex or substring imho.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you need this code to run very very efficiently. You should be worried about what is readable for you and your team (sometimes thats substring, split etc and sometimes thats regex). Only you can really decide.

Answer (score 1):

just use String.Split

```
        string CCstring = "CC01=50 CC02=300 CC03=500 CC04=40";
        var result = CCstring.Split(' ')
            .Select(s => s.Split('='))
            .ToDictionary(kv => kv[0], kv => Convert.ToInt64(kv[1]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your CCstring it will be definitely faster to walk through the string characters just once. Sure it doesn't worth that until you have tons of such strings.

So, yep, it's easier to use just `string.Split` once for spaces, and once for each fragmet to split by '='.